# Setting up communication between multiple iOS devices using NSNetServices class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multipeer-connectivity, nsnetservice

I am able to set up communication between multiple devices using `NSNetServices` class but only when those all devices are on same wifi network. Is it possible to make all the devices communicate regardless of the network availability, means it shouldn't matter if they are connected to same network or not connected to any network at all, just their wifi and bluetooth is on. 
And I don't wanna do it using `MultipeerConnectivity` framework.

Comment: `NSNetService` uses multicast which is typically limited to a single network segment (you can configure multicast forwarding but typically not across the Internet). It certainly can't work without any network connection.  Multi peer framework uses wifi or Bluetooth and is probably the easiest way of achieving what you are after